# Notification android (FCM)

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I want to customize notification layout when app closed and notification arrives a default notification is shown where I want a custom notification to be displayed even if app the closed.

The following is my code for Firebase `onMessageReceievd`

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d("remoteMessage",String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getFrom()));

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e("MyFirebaseMsgService", "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                sendPushNotificationData(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MyFirebaseMsgService", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendPushNotification(String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()),String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: where did you implement the custom layout. Can you pls post the code?

Answer (score 0):

I used `BitTextStyle()` to add highlighted text in notification.

```
return new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_mono)
       .setContentTitle(title)
       .setContentText(message)
       .setLargeIcon(icon)
       .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.notification_color))
       .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title))
       .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message).setSummaryText("#hashtag"))
       .setShowWhen(true)
       .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Comment: Ok but when app is destroy that time default system tray how to customize layout

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g97m0mgLXI    This Tutorial Will Help You.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase [Remote message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage) has `notification` and `data` fields. According to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) Firebase handles `remoteMessage.notification` automatically and pass `remoteMessage.data` into intent extras when your app is closed. But when your app is active `remoteMessage` comes to your receiver and handled by it. But there are few scenarios which depends on `remoteMessage` state. See the table in documentation. So, if you want to handle all notification even when your app is closed, you need to put all your data into `remoteMessage.data` field. In this case Firebase will deliver remote message directly into your receiver and there you can create custom layout with your data.